# Show $a\in G$ is contained in $Z(G)$ iff $Z(a)=G$ for center and centralizer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

The center of a group $G$ is defined as the set $Z(G):= \{a\in G\mid \forall b\in G : ab=ba\}$ and the centralizer of an element $a\in G$ is defined as the set $Z(a) := \{b\in G\mid ab=ba\}$.

How can one show that an element $a\in G$ is contained in $Z(G)$ iff $Z(a)=G$ ?

Comment: I really think you should do this exercise yourself.  It is a tautology.  Take an element of $Z(G)$ and show that $Z(a)=G$.  Then assume $Z(a)=G$ and show that $a$ satisfies the condition to be in $Z(G)$.  Each direction is *one step*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$Z(a)=G\iff \forall\,x\in G\;,\;\;ax=xa\iff a\in Z(G)$$

Comment: I dont understand, what do you mean by $Z(a)=G\iff \forall\,x\in G$ ? The for all x belongs to $\forall x: ax=xa\iff a\in Z(G)$ doesnt it?

Comment: $\;Z(a)=G\;$ means that the centralizer of $\;a\;$ is the *whole group*, which means that **any** element in $\;G\;$ centralizes $\;a\;$ , which means $\;ax=xa\;\;\forall\,x\in G\;$ , where $\;\forall\,x\in G=$ for all x in G.